# How to Hittest Grid ColumnDefinition?

Tags: wpf, events, hittest

I am making kind of WPF Designer. I want to find out `ColumnDefinition` i have clicked on to delete it from grid control. I will take care of those children who "are in that ColumnDefinition".
Can i get it from `sender` argument of click event handler?
Now im checking if `e.GetPosition` is in range of `ColumnDefinition.ActualWidth` but i wonder if there is more beautiful solution.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Deletion of a ColumnsDefiniton won't delete your grid's child. You need to call grid.Children.Remove(child) in order to remove a visual child from the grid.

Answer (score 1):

From within your click event handler:

```
int columnIndex = Grid.GetColumn((UIElement)sender);
```

where sender if a direct grid's child.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to capture a click on ColumnDefinition anyway? Is virtual, it does not have any actual body, it is only a hint for Grid on how you want to layout its content.
So you have to set handlers on content objects, not on ColumnDefinition.

### If you really need to capture a click on the whole surface of a grid cell, you may try to place a white (or other color the same as background) Reactangle inside it and capture a click on it.

Some clarification on how WPF Grid works.
When you add some controls to the Grid, they all become its children.

```
<Grid>
    <Button/>
    <TextBox/>
    <Label/>
</Grid>
```

And they all will be displayed not regarding how you have configured Column or RowDefinitions.
Column and RowDefinitions only tell Grid how you want to aling all the existing elements inside it, but they are not containers, they don't hold elements inside.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
    <Button/><!-- this is identical to Grid.Column="0"-->
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

In this example we have created three ColumnDefinitions, even from the grid XAML you can see, that controls are not inside definitions. They are used just like ruler guides to align content.
Then you set attached properties on the elements to tell the grid where you want to put your elements. 
When grid begins layout, it will see, that there are three elements, and three ColumnDefinitions, and will try to positions elements as ColumnDefinitions says.
But if you remove or change ColumnDefinitions in the runtime, grid will just realign controls in a new way.
If you want to hide some elements, you have to hide them, not ColumnDefinition.

Comment: i need to remove it or make changes in the width

Comment: If you remove ColumnDefinition, you will just trash your Grid layout, but will not remove content. You don't understand how Grid works.

Comment: You see i am making a designer and i intentional want to delete ColumnDefinition considering changing layout of those childre who were inside.